# Hide specific folder from an advanced search in win XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-search

How to hide a hidden folder from [advanced search](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302347) option in windows XP ?

Suppose we have an important folder which is hidden and when the user does an advanced search how to disable or hide that specific folder from an advanced search in win XP . Is there settings to be done ?

Comment: XP Pro: read [To set, view, change, or remove file and folder permissions](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/acl_set_permissions.mspx?mfr=true); XP Home: ???

Comment: XP Home: read [How to take ownership of a file or a folder in Windows XP](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/308421/en). If you are running Windows XP Home Edition, you must start the computer in safe mode, and then log on with an account that has administrative rights in order to access the Security tab

Comment: We are using XP pro

Answer (score 0):

To hide the folder from advanced search in xp

Click on Start -> Search ->Advanced options -> Modify preferences-> Modify parameters of files and folders search,Now check Advanced search,click on the arrows below more advanced options, then uncheck "search in hidden files and folders"

This would prevent the listing of hidden files during advanced search.

Comment: If we uncheck "search in hidden files and folders" search result will not show all the hidden files in the computer. But I just wanted to hide specific folder from advanced search .